# Degrees of freedom of likelihood ratio test with equal dimension on the null and the parameter space?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, likelihood-ratio, degrees-of-freedom

Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be iid samples from a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and consider the hypotesis

$$H_0:\theta\in\Theta_0,\,\,\,\,\,\,vs\,\,\,\,\,\,H_1:\theta\in\Theta _{0}^c$$

where $\Theta _{0} = \{\mu>0,\sigma^2>1\}$, $\theta=(\mu,\sigma)$. Let $\Lambda(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ be the likelihood ratio test

$${\displaystyle \Lambda (x_1,\dots,x_n)={\frac {\sup\{\,{\mathcal {L}}(\theta \mid x):\theta \in \Theta _{0}\,\}}{\sup\{\,{\mathcal {L}}(\theta \mid x):\theta \in \Theta \,\}}},}$$

What is the number of degrees of freedom of the $\chi^2$ distribution here? Usually, it is the dimension of $\Theta$ minus the dimension of $\Theta_0$, but in this case, both spaces have dimension 2.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test

Comment: The likelihood ratio approaches a $\chi^2$ distribution for *nested* models.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Isn't $\Theta_0\subset\Theta$?

Comment: The problem isn't "nesting" *per se,* but the fact that one model is differentiated from the other in terms of inequality constraints.  That is, there is no difference at all between the two models unless a constraint applies, in which case your estimate is at the *boundary* of $\Theta_0,$ implying the $\chi^2$ approximation will be (probably grossly) wrong. In effect, the concept of "degrees of freedom" becomes both irrelevant and misleading.

Comment: (Continued) Ordinarily situations like this are handled by reducing the submodel to a lower-dimensional space, but this is such an unnatural pair of null and alternative hypotheses (since they are not complementary) it is not obvious how to proceed.  Are you sure you have correctly stated both hypotheses?

Comment: @whuber The fact that they are not complementary was a typo, sorry. So, is the LRT applicable in this case?

Comment: Once you observe at least one of the suprema is attained (with probability $1$) on the boundary between the hypotheses, the problem looks more ordinary.  You have a model lying along a one-dimensional manifold-with corners nested within a two-dimensional model.